# Server running an OS

Tags: operating-system

How do I know if my server has a OS. How do I know if it is only a media device to store files on? I want to know if it has an OS or if I need to install an OS onto it to help with my work.

Comment: Does it load an operating system when you turn it on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what sort of server you're talking about, how did you manage to get it etc.
In all cases the first thing I'd do is to turn on the server and see what's going on on the screen (or KVM if you're using a VM on a local hypervisor/VPS).
If you don't see any splash screen, any lines showing up on screen indication some services being started or you get some prompts called `Operating system not found` then yeah - most likely you don't have any OS and you should start looking for some OS to install on that server to make it work.

If you don't know what's on the server, I suggest you to run some Ubuntu LiveDVD and see what's on the drive. In this way you won't delete anything from the server and you could get some more insight what's on the drive.

Comment: Thanks for the help, turns out is has an OS.

Answer (score 4):

Your question doesn't really make sense? What do you mean if it's only a media device to store files on? Is your server a USB?

If your server boots past it's BIOS into something else then it has an operating system

Comment: Thanks for the help, turns out is has an OS.